# How to disable other component when select one of two radio button in JAVA

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

So I want to disable other component when I select one of my radio button. The radio button are rbNoKK, and rbDariDaftarKK. Each of the button have other component like JTextFiled, JCheckBox, and JCombobox like this :

[image: the screenshot of my radio button]

E.g how can I disable the JComboBox in radio button 2 (which is named "rbDariDaftarRekening") when I select the first radio button named rbNoKK. I tried to make method like this but it didn't work

```
public void cekRadioButton(){
    if(rbNoKK.isSelected()){
        cbDaftarNoKK.setEnabled(false);
    }
    else if(rbDariDaftarKK.isSelected()){
        txtNoKK.setEnabled(false);
        chkTambahNoKK.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to defined an `ActionListener` to enable/disable your `Component` based on the value of the `JRadioButton`. See [`AbstractButton.addActionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addActionListener%28java.awt.event.ActionListener%29)

Comment: Thank you it works with the actionlistener :)